# On Mac, file association for image files keeps changing to Grab, when I want Preview instead

Tags: macos, file-association, preview.app, macos-highsierra, grab

For some reason, since a few weeks ago, every once in a while the file association for images like .jpg files will change to Grab (a built-in utility which is used for taking screenshots).

I'm on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (the latest).

I want them to be opened with Preview, though, so I always change them back by opening Get Info on a .jpg file, changing Open With to Preview, and clicking "Change All". This works for a day or two, and then suddenly the association will revert back to Grab.

How can I fix this permanently so it doesn't keep changing back to Grab?

Comment: The most plausible thing I can think of is that some program or script is changing it. I'd check frequently to see when it changes, and when it does try to figure what you've done/programs you've run since the last change that might have done it.

Comment: Yeah, for the time being, I am checking the file associations once a day, then when it changes, I'll try and recall what I did in the past 24 hours. That's the simple way of narrowing it down for now.

Comment: @Gary I'm suffering from the exact same problem. VERY annoying. Did you ever manage to find out what is changing the file associations?

Comment: By the way I also noticed whenever this happens, when I right-click on an image and choose Open With... then the Preview app is not in there for some reason. But if I choose Other, I can select Preview.app in the list manually, and then it works again.

Comment: I've seen this problem, too.  JPGs have been shifting to Photoshop, even when I haven't run Photoshop in a while.  Yesterday, VMWare Fusion VMs were associated with Terminal.